# Split and compare the splitted elements

Tags: r

I have a data.frame (9 columns and 5 rows) that looks like:

> ```
>  List    Count 
>   R472    1   RAP1GDS1    AKT1    ERC1    ZRSR2   SMAD4   ASXL1   NA
>   R47     1   TCF12       DICER1  OLIG2   GATA3   CLP1    SMAD4   NA
>   R844    2   RNF213      LHFP    MLLT6   TTL    SMARCA4   AKT2   TSC2
>   R845    2   MLL         MYH9    FBXW7   VTI1A   CLP1     NF2    PIK3CA
>   R975    2   TCF12       ELK4    PDE4DIP FANCG   ZRSR2   FAM123B FCRL4
> ```

I would like to split the data into groups according to column "Count" and then make a comparison of the corresponding elements to find the differences (and to annotate them) and the similarities. 
Ex:
Desired output:

> ```
>  Count1      Common   How_many_similar   Differences   How_many_different
>              SMAD4           1            RAP1GDS1             10  
>                                             AKT1
>                                             ERC1
>                                             ....
> ```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: How would you classify the hypothetical case that an element is common to two of three lists in a group? Is that a `Common` element or a `Different` one? Or a third classification?

Comment: Hi Ben, I just would like to know what are the elements that differ (and that are equal) between the two lists for ex belonging from Group 6 according to "Count" column. Just a comparison.

Comment: But for count 7 there are three lists, hence my question.

Comment: Okk, so in that case, the comparison will be between three lists. 7 is not equal to the number of lists per group but is equal to the number of elements of the group. In fact all the lists in group 7 are composed of 7 genes (elements).

Comment: How is your data represented in R? Can you paste output from `dput` for your example input data?

Comment: Hi MvG. After dput, the output is structure(list(Letter = structure(c(416L, 413L, 829L, 830L, 974L, 
606L, 807L, 457L, 92L, 977L, 363L, 471L, 324L, 663L, 600L, 729L, 
1L, 727L, 643L, 714L, 755L, 827L, 145L, 309L, 853L, 972L, 150L,

Comment: @Bnf8, that won't fit into a comment, so better edit your question and include that data there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lacking details about how your input data is structured (`dput` would be great there!), it's hard to give precise information. After all, a data frame does not allow elements to be lists, nor does it allow rows to have different numbers of columns. So it's hard to tell how you split your input into chunks by count.

For the comparison, I suggest you transform all the data for your comparison to a factor, and then you use `table` on that factor to compute the number of times each element occurs in a given vector. Which means you'll have to simply concatenate the rows, and any data structure which provides the rows for a single group as a single vector would be very suitable for this.